# how to take a path name and remove the final two folder names

Tags: bash

I have spent a good deal of time looking around and cannot find a solution to my specific question. I would really appreciate any help.

I have a folder path that I would like to remove the final two folder names from. I have tried finding something similar to `dirname` as `dirname` only strips the last folder name.

As an example, I have the path `/This/Is/The/Path/` and I would like to script a way to remove the final two folders and return `/This/Is/`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use parameter expansion:

```
dir=/This/Is/The/Path/
dir=${dir%/*/*/}/  # Remove pattern on the right.
echo "$dir"
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you do like this ?

```
$ a="/This/Is/The/Path"
$ echo ${a%/*/*}
```

output:

```
/This/Is
```